# The fluid field dropdown is overflowing the bottom of the control panel

Tags: fields, fluid-field

I have around a dozen fields in a fluid field and as I add them the add fluid field drop down over flows the bottom of the page and I cant see most of them. (see image below).Is this a bug or recognized problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this recent bug](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/issues/115) in the expression engine github, it sounds like some UI related improvements are on the way. It would likely be worthwhile to report this issue so the EE team is aware of it.